# Is there any way making calendar widget in Flutter? (android studio)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[image]

I want to make home calendar widget using flutter, is there any example of way to make it???

Answer (score -1):

A good place to start, either by using them or by getting inspired by their methods, is to look for appropriate packages on pub.dev

A quick search yields me:
https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_view

https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar

https://pub.dev/packages/cr_calendar

Among many others. You can use those and customize them to fit your needs. If you want to implement something yourself, you can try using a package like `flutter_grid_button`:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_grid_button

### Edit

I see you meant to make it an actual Widget (in the traditional Android/iOS sense, not in the Flutter sense). For that, you can use something like the `home_widget` package:
https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget
But you'll need to write the Widget code itself in native iOS/Android code, and cannot use Flutter views as-is, as I understand.

Comment: Keep in mind, by the way, that StackOverflow is normally meant for programming questions about specific problems you're facing, not general questions like this

Comment: sorry fravolt.. I will keep in mind, and thank you for answer